# Could peer query before instantiation when two org one orderer?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

[From fabric document](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#what-s-happening-behind-the-scenes),there are some words as following:
A query against the value of “a” is issued to peer0.org1.example.com. The chaincode was previously installed on peer0.org1.example.com, so this will start a container for Org1 peer0 by the name of dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-1.0. The result of the query is also returned. No write operations have occurred, so a query against “a” will still return a value of “100”.

Why query operation could create container for Org1 peer0 by the name of dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-1.0 , usually we should instantiation firstly?

Answer (score 1):

> Why query operation could create container for Org1 peer0 by the name of dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-1.0 , usually we should instantiation firstly?

The instantiation of chaincode done only once against specific peer, which eventually spans container with chaincode on that specific peer. While you might query against another peer, therefore:

1. Chaincode has to be installed on that peer
2. It will check whenever chaincode instantiated and it already has chaincode container running, if container is not running it will run it.

The reason to run container is simple, the query has to be against chaincode, which is actually an invocation of one of the function defined by chaincode.

Answer (score 0):

You have an explanation about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45728688/what-is-chaincode-container-in-hyperledger-fabric). However, I paste the answers.

The purpose of the chaincode container is to ensure isolation of the smart contract's execution from the peer itself, so that a smart contract (chaincode) cannot crash or even access the peer because of an error or malicious code. When you instantiate a chaincode, the peer populates a container image with the chaincode and invokes the Docker management API to deploy that image. If the container isn't running, it will start a new one. Once running, all transactions and proposals received by the peer will be transmitted to that container for execution.

The chaincode container runs the smart contract logic. When you instantiate a chaincode, the Init method is simulated and returned to the client for sending to the orderer for creation of a new transaction (init transaction, that binds the chaincode to the channel). That's why the container starts up, if it hasn't been running before.